# How do I select a 1 as a bit in a sql-server view?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I want to create a view in which I select something like the following:

```
select id, name, 1 as active
from users
```

However, I want the active field, which I am creating in the select statement (it doesn't exist in the table), to be a bit field. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use the CONVERT operator.

```
SELECT id, name, CONVERT(bit, 1) AS active
FROM users
```

CAST or CONVERT will work.

Answer (score 15):

```
select id, name, CAST(1 AS bit) as active
from users
```

`1` is the display for a true bit. What are your trying to achieve.

Doing

```
select CAST('true' AS bit) as active
```

returns `1` also.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you cast it to bit:

```
select id, name, cast(1 as bit) as active
from users
```

This can also be useful to improve performance when comparing to a bit value in some situations:

```
select id, name
from users
where active = cast(1 as bit)
```

(In this example it might make no practical difference, but I have seen an actual difference in more complicated queries.)

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, name, Convert(bit, 1) as active
from users
```

Is what you probably are wanting to do.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have True and False constants.